# Alphanumeric Number for my sales invoice

Tags: c#, sql

I want alphanumeric numbers in C# for my sales invoice, and to store it into a SQL database.

For examplee, LG/slae/1000, LG/sales/1001, etc.

Here is my current code. It works only for int values. How can I modify it to work with alphanumeric values?

```
     public class SALESINVOICE
{
    public string Sales_Invoice {get; set;}
    public string Customer_Name {get; set;}
     public string   Mobile_No {get; set;}
       public string Address {get; set;}
      public string  Item_Name {get; set;}
      public string  Item_Code {get; set;}
      public string  Dept {get; set;}
      public string  Date {get; set;}
       public int Qty {get; set;}
       public int Rate {get; set;}
       public int Vat_tax {get; set;}
       public int Amount {get; set;}
       public int Payment_Type {get; set;}
       public int Purchase_ID { get; set; }

       string myConnection = ("user id=username;" +
                                   "password=password;server="";" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=""; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30");

    # region
    public void retriveData()
    {
        string selQuery="select sales_invoice from sales";
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn= new SqlConnection (myConnection);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (selQuery, conn);
            Sales_Invoice=(string)cmd.ExecuteScalar()+1;
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            Sales_Invoice=LG/SALES/1000;
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking.  Please trim down that code block to only the relevant parts and try to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: It's very difficult to debug without the database schema. Do you mind posting the schema of table 'sales'?

Comment: Is this question about compiler error? There should be atleast 2 errors. Post the errors, if that's what your question is about.

Comment: Are you asking how to store alphanumeric values in SQL? Well that's just a `varchar`.

Comment: sir actually what i need is i have to generate sales invoice number in alphanumeric format pls help me sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, your `ExecuteScalar` returns a string like "LG/SALES/1000". You are trying to add an integer value (1) to that, which will not work. You probably want to *parse* (i.e. the `Split()` method) the string into 3 parts, cast the last part as an integer, then add 1 to that integer. Then you can cast the updated integer back to a `String`, use the `Join()` method to put the parts back together (delimited by "/") so that you can use/store the new value.

Also, in your `catch` block, you are assigning a value that is obviously alphanumeric (a string), but you don't have double-quotes around the value. This will never work either.

Fix at least these two things, and perhaps clarify your question if you still have one.

**EDIT, after comment from OP**

Ok, so here is the code for a simple WinForms app (1 form, 5 texboxes, and a button, all of which are self explanatory when you see the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Increment();
    }

    private void Increment() 
    { 
        //Split the original string
        //NOTE: textBox1 already contains the text "LG/SALES/1000" in this example
        string[] tempArray = textBox1.Text.Split('/');

        //Display resulting array just for verification
        textBox2.Text = tempArray[0];
        textBox3.Text = tempArray[1];
        textBox4.Text = tempArray[2];

        //Convert last part to an int and add 1
        string tempId = tempArray[2]; 
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(tempId);
        id = id + 1; 

        //Make new alpha-numeric value with incremented id
        string autoId = "LG/SALES/" + String.Format("{0:0000000}", id); 
        textBox5.Text = autoId;
    }

}
```

Notice that I used your code pretty much as you posted in the comment. So, in other words, it works. I'm not sure why you want to format the "incremented" number the way you are (you make the original "1000" get incremented and formatted with leading zeros so the result becomes "00001001" - you might want to use just "G" for General format, or simply the `.ToString()` method of the int, but that's your choice.

Hope this helps!

Comment: sir i had just tried split method, but the value is didn't show my label18 here is my code 



private void Increment()
       
 {
           
 var str = label18.Text;
       
 var tempArray = str.Split('/');
    
enter code here
           
string tempId = tempArray[2];

int id = Convert.ToInt32(tempId);

id = id + 1;

string autoId = "LG/SALES/" + String.Format("{0:0000000}", id);

label18.Text = autoId;

Comment: See my edited answer above, but also, please take advantage of the debugger and **STEP through your code**, observing the variables, etc. It's much easier to see what is really going on in your procedures if you use the debugger.